# Ordering Furthest from a Given Permutation

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

I made a competition draft with some friends of mine and I've been wondering some of the math behind it:

Suppose there are $n$ people in a competition, and a group of people pick what they think the results are going to be. At the end of the competition, the following metric is used to measure error:

$E(expected, actual) = \Sigma_{i=1}^n | expectedRanking_{contestant_i} - actualRanking_{contestant_i}|$

So for example, if someone placed 4th but I guessed them to be first, that would be 3 points added to my error.

1. What is the max error possible? How would you find this case?
2. Suppose the $k$th placing is a tie. For this case, let's use the actual ranking as whatever is closer to the expected, $k$ or $k-1$. So, if person A ties for 3rd (so no 4th place technically), and I expected them to get 1st, my error increases by 2, but if I expected them to get 5th, my error increases by 1. What is the max possible error now? And how would you find this case now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is known as **deviation distance**, and is maximized when the ordering is the reverse of the true ordering. For the proof see

```
More distance functions for order-based encodings
Ronald, S

1998 IEEE International Conference on Evolutionary Computation Proceedings. 
IEEE World Congress on Computational Intelligence (Cat. No.98TH8360), 1998, 
p.558-563
```

I don't understand the second question. It is obvious that the maximal distance occurs when there are no ties, in which case see above.